# Authentication Password Problem

Tags: 13.04

We recently bought a new PC at the office. The default operating system is Ubuntu 14.04. Everything was fine until we downloaded apps needed for our work. Everytime we try to install it, the computer asks for a password. Can you help me with the password?

Comment: What was the process that you used to initiate the install.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs will call on the root password during the install process.  By default, Ubuntu doesn't have a root password so you won't be able to type in the correct password.

If the install program is a commanline from the terminal you can prefix the command with `sudo`.  If you have `sudo` access, it would then prompt you for the same password that you used for logging in to your account.